# Function changing input

Tags: java, recursion, function

I would like to go from one number to another. For example if I started at 6 and my goal was 10 I want a function that on every pass would bring me from 6 towards 10 or if I had the number 14 and my goal was 9 it would count down from 14 towards 9.So far I have (this is written in Processing a Java Api but there is essentially no difference from regualr Java, draw is just a continuous loop)

```
int x=100;
void draw(){
  x=towards(x,10);
  println(x);

}

int towards(int current ,int target){
  if(current!=target){
    if (current <target){
      current=current+1;
    }
    else {
      current=current-1;
    }
  }
  return current;
}
```

this gives me the results I would like but I would like to have everything in side of the towards() function. When I replace X with a variable it of course resets it self to the static variable.

To sum it up how can I pass a variable to a function and have that variable thats been passed change on every subsequent pass. I have looked into recursion as a solution but that of  just brings me to a final solution. I can pass the count to an array but wouldn't like to do that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java uses pass-by-value, and so you cannot change the parameters (although if the parameters is a user-defined object, you can change the object pointed-to by the parameter, but not the parameter, itself).

One thing you might consider, though, is to create an iterator type interface:

```
// RangeIterator.java
public class RangeIterator implements Iterator<Integer>
{
   public RangeIterator(int first, int last){
       _first = first;
       _last = last;
       if ( _first <= _last ){
           _step = 1;
       }else{
           _step = -1;
       }
   }

   public RangeIterator(int first, int last, int step){
       if ( step == 0 ){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Step must be non-zero.");
       }
       _first = first;
       _last = last;
       _step = step;
   }

   public boolean hasNext(){
       if ( _step < 0 ){
           return _first > _last;
       } else {
           return _first < _last;
       }
   }

   public Integer next(){
       int result = _first;
       _first += _step;
       return result;
   }

   public void remove(){
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented.");
   }

   private int _first;
   private int _last;
   private int _step;
}

// Range.java
public class Range implements Iterable<Integer>
{
     public Range(int first, int last){
       _first = first;
       _last = last;
       if ( _first <= _last ){
           _step = 1;
       }else{
           _step = -1;
       }
     }

     public Range(int first, int last, int step){
       if ( step == 0 ){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Step must be non-zero.");
       }
       _first = first;
       _last = last;
       _step = step;
     }

     public Iterator<Integer> iterator(){ 
           return new RangeIterator(_first,_last,_step); 
     }

     private int _first;
     private int _last;
     private int _step;
}
```

With the code above, you could then conveniently write something like:

```
Range range = new Range(x,100);
for (int val : range){
    println(val);
}
```

Since I see that you come from a Python background, this should feel very much like:

```
for val in xrange(x,100):
    print val;
```

You can implement the [Iterable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) and [Iterator](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) interfaces in order to provide your own generators that can be used in the Java for-each loops. Basically, `for (Type identifier1 : identifier2)` iterates through the contents of *identifier2* which needs to be an Iterable type, and on each iteration assigns the current element to *identifier1*. The loop is just syntactic sugar for iterating over *identifier2*.iterator().

Answer (score 0):

Java *always* passes `int` arguments by value. If you want to keep state around (particularly writable state) then keep it in an object and (probably) make `towards()` a method of that class.

Comment: that would definitely work...Does Java have anything similar to a Python generator? Should I like towards objects as a solution more often? I would hate to create an object for this every time I needed it.

Comment: Java's an OO language with a pretty efficient memory allocation system so might as well use it. :-) I've seen things like Python generators, but it might be simpler to just make an `Iterator` if you're thinking of using the generator to return a sequence of values.

Comment: @Doodle, for a generator, see my solution; I have created a range iterator that you can use.